How to compare skewed performance data?
I'm performing a database performance test on a virtual machine such as virtualbox machine or kvm VM. My test is like this:
I run ten times, each run I insert 10000 row into database(let's say it's just single-threaded and it's done in a few seconds) and count the total consuming time. I thought I could calculate average time of ten runs and compare the average number once I have done some optimizations.
However I find the time gap(such as 20% between max value and min value) is too high among each run, probably caused by kernel scheduler. So I think comparing average value is meaningless. What kind of math metrics I can use to compare so that I can say the performance increase by x% after some optimizations, althought data is still not very stable. I don't know whether it exists in such environment, but if exists, it should be relatively stable among each run, right ?
I may run the test on bare-metal machine which is likely more stable, but we have limited resources. So I have to live with VM for the moment.

There are tons of processes running in the database. It's normal that you get 20% difference between tests. In my experience, SQL optimization typically produces performance gains/losses of orders of magnitude, not just a few percentage points. You should be able to spot those gains using your current approach.

And... running on bare metal won't make much of a difference.
